# What does partition BETWEEN two sets mean?

Tags: definition, set-partition

Partition of a space is a just bunch of subsets of the space such as any element belongs to exactly one subset.

However, when we have two disjoint closed subsets A, B of some space X, than what is an arbitrary partition P *between* A, B? Does it mean that this partition randomly sorts the rest of X into either A, or B? When $A \cup B$ $\neq X$, should I understand it such as the partition P just creates two equivalence classes from all elements somehow?

Thank you very much.

Source: I have seen this in Van Mill´s book on topology of function spaces.
Exact expression from the book:
[image]

Comment: I think it would be best if you quote the book verbatim instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Added for the better context

Comment: I believe it means that $A_i$ and $B_i$ are in distinct partitions.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You mean in distincts subsets belonging to the partition $L_i$?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another definition of the same concept.

Let $X$ be a space.
An closed set $L_i$ *separates* two closed subsets of $X$, $A_i$ and $B_i$ if $X - L_i$ can be written as a union of two separated sets, one containing $A_i$ and the other containing $B_i$. This is basically the claim "$L_i$ is partition between $A_i$ and $B_i$".

If the intersection of all such $L_i$ for all pairs $(A_i, B_i)$ is nonempty, then the family of pairs $(A_i, B_i)$ is called *essential*.

So the meaning of "partition between two sets" is a closed set such that when we "cut it out" of the space, the two sets can still be separated.

**Source:** *LEONARD R. RUBIN - NONCOMPACT HEREDITARILY STRONGLY INFINITE DIMENSIONAL SPACES*

Answer (score 2):

This just means any choosing of $A_i$ and $B_i$. So it needs to hold for $$(\bigcap_{i \in G_1} A_i) \cap (\bigcap_{j \in G_2}B_i)$$ with $G_1 \dot{\cup} \ G_2  = G$

Comment: What exactly needs to hold for that intersection? Sorry for being pedantic, but the exact wording is crucial for me in this case to understand the definition.

Comment: Here partition doesn't have a formal definition, so it needs to be derived from context. I would interpret this as $L_i$ is either $A_i$ or $B_i$. In total that would mean that it has to hold for any Intersection of any combination of multiple $A_i$ and $B_j$ such that there is no Index k with $A_k$ and $B_k$ are both choosen.